# How to restrict access to sections of monolithic Azure app service

Tags: azure-networking, azure-web-apps

I am wondering if it is possible (using an App Service & Slots) to stop public access to certain elements of an application.

We currently have an application that consists of a number of web applications that communicate with a large number of WCF services. I have been looking for (with no success) a way that the application can communicate with the WCF services - but they are not publicly available. I tried binding the WCF endpoints to localhost, but then the application wasn't able to see them.

So - if someone were to visit http://myapplication/Services/* in their browser then it would return 404s but the application can see them internally. I've found various guides for routing tables and virtual networks etc. to similar things but they don't seem to be able to achieve this for internal traffic within a monolithic app.